# How can I copy a file from my assets folder into my SD card at first run of the app in Android?

Tags: android, android-assets

How can I copy a file from my assets folder into my SD card at first run of the app in Android ?  I need to know the exact steps please.

Answer (score 1):

1.first run: check if a sharedPreference value that you put has existed before. if not, it's the first run and you should also add the value. if it exists, it's not the first run. example:

```
SharedPreferences pref=PreferenceManager.getdefaultsharedpreferences‎(this);
if(!pref.contains("firstInstall"))
  {
  //first install, so do some stuff...
  pref.edit().putBoolean("firstInstall",true).commit();
  }
```

2.add a permission in the manifest to write to the external storage .

3.use inputStream to read a file from the assets , as such:

> ```
>  AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
>  InputStream is assetManager.open("myFile.txt");
> ```

4.use outputStream to write to the target file from the inputStream , as such:

> ```
>   FileOutputStream os=null;
>   try
>     {
>     File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
>     File file = new File(root , "myFile.txt");
>     os = new FileOutputStream(file);
>     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
>     int len;
>     while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0) 
>        os .write(buf, 0, len);
>     }
>   finally
>     {
>     if(is!=null)
>       is.close();
>     if(os!=null)
>       os.close();
>     }
> ```

Comment: Please, to which particular file am I going to add these codes?

Comment: How do I check if a sharedPreference value that I put has existed before?

Comment: @KayodeSowole about the sharedPreferences, i've now updated my answer. about the files, you can put the code either into the initial activity (splash screen for example or the main activity) or the class that extends Application (and set the manifest to point to it). in any case, if it takes a long time to copy the file, please use a background thread (like asyncTask), so that the user won't have ANR (application not responding) dialog.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void copyAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
    }
    for(String filename : files) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
          in = assetManager.open(filename);
          File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
          out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
          copyFile(in, out);
          in.close();
          in = null;
          out.flush();
          out.close();
          out = null;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
        }       
    }
}
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [standard JAVA I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).  Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get to the root of external storage (which, on some devices, is an SD card). You have to add this to your persmissions: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
You can use the following method for copying the file when you have the paths:

```
public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: To which file will I add this method?